# Get standard system buttons in Interface Builder on Mac

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

Is there a way to get system buttons like the traffic lights or full screen button in Interface Builder?  I am building a custom top toolbar and would like to have them in it, but would prefer to do it in IB instead of code.

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to use `-[NSWindow standardWindowButton:]` or `+[NSWindow standardWindowButton:forStyleMask:].